# Jenkinsfile how to capture multiple exceptions in parallel branches

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a jenkins script, which used by jenkins pipeline job:

```
 try{
     parallel branch1: {
          //some function that may throw exception
     }, branch2: {
          //some function that may throw exception
     }, branch3: {
          //some function that may throw exception
     }
 }catch(Exception e){
     //Need to gather the error information together.
     //if there is only 1 error then that's it; 
     //if there are 2 or more errors then concatenate them or so, etc.. and print it. 
 }
```

How can I get all the exceptions in these branches? or I just cannot do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can somehow capture whatever your errors are into a variable, capture the output and store it for the end stage. Then all you have to do is set the build result per stage as a success to prevent the job failing prematurely. See [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/885/cleanest-way-to-prematurely-exit-a-jenkins-pipeline-job-as-a-success) for how to do that. Finally, concatenate your variables at the end.

The final result might look like (semi-pseudocode);

```
try{
    parallel branch1: {
         //some function that may throw exception
         error1=$(echo error)
         currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
         return
    }, branch2: {
         //some function that may throw exception
         error2=$(echo error)
         currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
         return
    }, branch3: {
         //some function that may throw exception
         error3=$(echo error)
         currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
         return
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    //gather the error information together (if there 1 error then just it, if there are 2 errors then concatenate 2 errors together, etc) and print it. 
    print $error1 + $error2 + $error3
}
```

I might even take it outside of a try/catch and just rely on setting your `currentBuild.result`s to handle the errors.